# How to check if XSD schema is well formed?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Is there a class or commonly used method for programmatically checking if an XSD schema is well formed (In the case where a user has selected an XSD file)?

Or should I treat it like any other XML and validate it against the W3 2001 schema somehow?

My XSD schema to be checked starts like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Configuration" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

Maybe the `XmlReader` might essentially do this, if it chokes on an invalid XSD when validating the XML? **Update:** No, it doesn't. It just carries blithely on.

**Note**: This question concerns checking the *schema* is well formed, it is not about checking that some XML is valid according to a schema.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with C#... and you can just validate your XSD against the DTD or XSD from w3.org.  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question cited. This question is about validating schema documents; the other one is about validating instance documents using a schema.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I know that , ideally, an XSD should validate against the W3 schema. As stated in my first line though, I'd like to know how this is commonly achieved in .Net. Are there specific methods or does one treat it like any other XML? Is it normal to use a local copy of the W3 schema or require an internet connection and link to the live W3 copy? etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three interesting questions one could ask about a schema document:

1 Is it well-formed XML?

2 Is it valid XML in the sense that it conforms to the schema for schema documents?

3 Does it describe a valid schema, taking into account the prose rules in the XSD specification as well as the rules embodied in the schema for schema documents?

For the schema document to be usable, it has to satisfy (3), and I therefore see little point in checking (1) and (2) separately. But of course you can check well-formedness and validity in the same way as you check any other XML document.

To check (3), you should simply submit the schema to a schema processor, for example the native XSD 1.0 processor that comes with .NET (use `XmlSchemaSet.Compile()`), or the XSD 1.1 processor available in Saxon (use `SchemaManager.Compile()`).